# Discord.pyでmultiprocessingを使った時、正常に動作しない。

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Discord.pyでコマンドが実行された場合にmultiprocessingを利用し、ブロッキングされないようにしてタイマーを実行したいと思っています。
しかし実際に動作させようとすると正しく動作しません。（メッセージがコンソールに表示されず、反応もしない。）
解決法を知っている方がおりましたらご教授いただければと思います。
ファイルは以下の通りです。

main.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import multiprocessing
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",owner_id=ownerid)
bot.load_extension("subs")
@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.id==bot.owner_id):
        print("reload")
        bot.reload_extension("subs")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="エラー！",description="権限がありません",color=discord.Colour.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

subs.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import multiprocessing
import time
def thdtms():
    print("start")
    time.sleep(300)
    print("timer done")
    
class Greetings(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._last_member = None
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Ready!')
        print('Logged in as ---->', self.bot.user)
        print('ID:', self.bot.user.id)

    @commands.command()
    async def thdtm(self,ctx):
     if ctx.author.bot:
        return
     multi = multiprocessing.Process(target=thdtms)
     multi.start()
     
def setup(bot):
    return bot.add_cog(Greetings(bot))
```

Comment: [How to multiprocess with discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65354785)